# Puzzle Problem Basic Math Properties

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the definite answer for this question? $$(a-x)(b-x)(c-x)\ldots (z-x) =\: ?$$

Comment: HINT:  you have $x-x$

Comment: Hint: $...(w-x)(x-x)(y-x)...$

Comment: This has to have been posted before, since I've seen it several times in my life away from M.SE. But I see that the "related posts" starts with "Universal properties of de Rahm differentials" and doesn't get much more related...

Answer (score 2):

Note that one of the factors must then be $\;\color{blue}{\bf (x - x) = 0}$, making the entire product of factors equal to $$(a - x)(b - x)\ldots(w - x)\color{blue}{\bf (x - x)}(y - x)(z - x)\ldots = \color{blue}{\bf 0}$$

Comment: this is safely a comment already

Comment: @lab I was typing an answer while you commented. Relax.

Comment: my point is not the timing, but the volume

Comment: Well, this *is* an answer, so why would the volume be important? It belongs here and not in the comments part if the poster so wants. +1

Comment: +1 Your use of $\color{blue}{blue}$ color was great.
 Because,to better understand the the answer was very effective.

Comment: Nice use of color but I have the same problem every time I used it the letter $x$ is slightly changed!

Comment: That might be because I bold-faced the blue?